# How to serialize an object in python3?

Tags: python, file, serialization

I have created(still working on it) a simple phonebook **CLI** **application** using linked list in python.In main method I have created an object called **phone** and added some names and numbers.I need to save this object as *.ser* file and it should be able to open that again and make changes to that. I did that in java using **Serialization**(including file streams). But it is difficult to find a way in python to do that.Could someone give me a code to serialize that object and deserialize also?

My phonebook **CLI** **application** code is below,

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,name,number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.next = None
class List:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def InsertNumber(self,name,number):
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = Node(name,number)
        else:
            newNode = Node(name,number)
            temp = self.head
            temp2 = self.head
            if(newNode.name<self.head.name):
                newNode.next = self.head
                self.head = newNode
            else:
                while(temp is not None and newNode.name >= temp.name):
                    temp2 = temp
                    temp = temp.next
                temp2.next = newNode
                newNode.next = temp
    def Display(self):
        temp = self.head
        while(temp is not None):
            print("{0:<15}{1:<15}".format(temp.name,temp.number),end='\n')
            temp = temp.next
def Main():
    phone = List()
    phone.InsertNumber("Jeewantha","234242")
    phone.InsertNumber("Ahiru","r34535")
    phone.InsertNumber("Akila","52324")
    phone.InsertNumber("Zahira","24242")
    phone.InsertNumber("Amasha","234242")
    phone.Display()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: Look at the `pickle` module that comes with Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pickle.html) built in module that implements binary protocols for serializing and de-serializing a Python object structure.

To serialize the `phone` object,

```
import pickle

with open("phone.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(phone, f)
```

To deserialize the serialized object use,

```
with open("phone.pickle", "rb") as f:
    phone = pickle.load(f)
    phone.Display()
```