Convert a complex string representation of a list (containing tuples, which look like function calls) into a list
I am trying to create a fixture for unit testing. I retrieve data from an API and need data that looks like what I get from the API without making the call to the API. I need to create a number of list literals that capture different scenarios for the unit test. Here is the string representation of the list I'm trying to convert to a list:
[(3479865,
  PaginatedManagedEntityHeaders(
  success=True, 
  count=0, 
  rows=[
  ManagedEntityHeader(
  case_role='Reference',
  display_name='Person A',
  entity_type='PERSON', 
  unique_id=247878382, 
  is_active='1', 
  date_created=datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 18, 16, 29, 6, 535000, tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC))),
  ManagedEntityHeader(
  case_role='Reference', 
  display_name='Person B', 
  entity_type='PERSON', 
  unique_id=247563788, 
  is_active='0', 
  date_created=datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 8, 21, 4, 29, 631000, tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC)))]
))]

I have saved this as a JSON file: "test_fixture.json". I could also save it as a text file. It imports successfully as a string. I don't think I can create this list in Python code without receiving numerous errors, but maybe there is a way to do it. Here is what I have tried so far to convert the string to a list.
import os
import json
import ast
import re

the_file = os.path.join(r"test_fixture.json")

file_str = open(the_file).read()

meth1 = file_str.strip("][").split(", ")
# receive a list of 25 instead of a list of 1

meth2 = ast.literal_eval(file_str)
# ValueError: malformed node or string on line 2: <ast.Call object at 0x000002241687F8E0>

meth3 = json.loads(file_str)
# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

elements = re.findall(r"\d+", file_str)
meth4 = [int(x) for x in elements]
# receive a list of 20 instead of a list of 1

meth5 = eval(file_str)
# NameError: name 'PaginatedManagedEntityHeaders' is not defined

meth6 = list(map(int, file_str[1:-1].split(",")))
# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '(3479865'

Is there another method (meth_that_worked) that will successfully convert the string into a list of 1 element?
print(meth_that_worked) should produce output identical to the string representation of the list above.
print(type(meth_that_worked)) should produce <class 'list'>. print(len(meth_that_worked)) should produce 1.
Update
Based on some of the comments, I tried addressing the namespace errors received when executing eval(file_str) as follows:
def ManagedEntityHeader(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

def TzInfo(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

def UTC(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

Then I received the following error:
ValidationError: 2 validation errors for PaginatedManagedEntityHeaders
rows.0
  Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from [type=model_attributes_type, input_value=None, input_type=NoneType]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/model_attributes_type
rows.1
  Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from [type=model_attributes_type, input_value=None, input_type=NoneType]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/model_attributes_type

Then I created a function similar to the ones above to address this error:
def PaginatedManagedEntityHeaders(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

After doing this, a list was successfully created, but the list content was truncated compared to the original string representation of the list:
[(3479865, None)]


Edit the question to show the expected result list (formatted as code).

"I have saved this as a JSON file" - Why? It's clearly not JSON.

@nocomment  Results are same if saved as a text file. Previously used fixtures were JSON.

Why are you storing this link as a string/json? Depending on your use case, pickling might work better.

This is not JSON. Why don't you actually use JSON? Or a pickle? Or one of the many existing serialization formats? Why do you save the output of str(something) to a file as text? That doesnt make any sense. Don't do that

@TedM. the extension is irrelevant. The actual content of the file is what matters.

@AndrewYim it isn't being stored as JSON. That's one of the problems.

Anyway, what you basically want is eval(file_str), but the types you are using need to be available in the namespace. Again, fundamentally the problem you have here is that you've saves this output to begin with.

Unrestricted paren matching cannot be done with simple find-and-replace or regexes.  This is a computational theory issue with no work-around. You will need to develop a proper parser to do what you're thinking, I'd recommend a recursive parser.  Keeping in mind that python's recursion depth is 1000, and you may need to develop another way if your structures are very nested.

it doesn't loop similar to JSON so dirtyjson can't help. I think that idea with eval() is the simplest solution - but first it needs to defined classes PaginatedManagedEntityHeaders, ManagedEntityHeader - or at least fake functions which get correct number of parameters or with (*args, **kwargs).

@VoNWooDSoN you can just use the python parser: ast. But again, this is almost certainly overly complicating what the OP really wants to do

eval does not raise ValidationError. Please provide a [mcve]. It sounds like you are maybe using Pydantic. In any case, you should almost certainly use the actual classes that were used to create the original object. It is totally unclear what you are even trying to accomplish by just putting dummy functions that return None.

@juanpa.arrivillaga Your comments helped me arrive at a solution. The actual classes needed to be imported. I also needed to modify the string representation. Thank you!

@TedM. I really can't stress this enough, what you need to do is stop using this format to begin with

@juanpa.arrivillaga How would you suggest representing the data I get back from the API? Maybe I don't understand what you mean by "this format".

@TedM. I and others have given you many different suggestions, use pickle, use JSON, use a database if you want. Don't dump the string representation to a file a pretend it is a serialization format. It isn't.  You keep ignoring this. By "this format" I mean the format you have here, which again, is the result of someone doing something like f = open("test_fixture.json"); f.write(str(my_list)). Don't do that. That is what needs to be fixed here

It would be nice to see an example of how to use pickle or JSON to achieve the same thing I got.

@TedM. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61443632/how-to-serialize-an-object-in-python3?noredirect=1&lq=1

You'll want to parse it using a suitable grammar etc. If your list uses Python syntax you can use a library like astroid, e. g.:
from astroid import parse

list_code = '''
[
    ('example', 7),
    ('list', 'with'),
    'tuples',
    ()
]
'''

m = parse(list_code)
print(m.body[0].value.elts)

In this case m.body[0].value.elts will be a list of astroid AST nodes.
If you want actual python objects instead of AST nodes you can just use your 5th method:
list_code = '''
[
    ('example', 7),
    ('list', 'with'),
    'tuples',
    ()
]
'''

print(eval(list_code))

You got an error for this method because PaginatedManagedEntityHeaders was not defined. eval actually evaluates and runs python code, so you have to create/import every class/function that is called in the list before calling eval.

I am almost certain tehy don't want AST nodes (in that case, if all you want is the nodes, you could just use ast). It's better to avoid this altogether, though. The eval part is the most relevant part of this answer, IMO

Thank you for the suggested solution. I definitely want a python object. I've made an update to my original post based on using eval(), showing the errors and truncated list that I get.

The comments offered were critical in helping me arrive at a solution. I ended up needing to change tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC) to tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc as it seems that the previous syntax is deprecated. So, the string representation of the list I use is:
[(3479865,
  PaginatedManagedEntityHeaders(
  success=True, 
  count=0, 
  rows=[
  ManagedEntityHeader(
  case_role='Reference',
  display_name='Person A',
  entity_type='PERSON', 
  unique_id=247878382, 
  is_active='1', 
  date_created=datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 18, 16, 29, 6, 535000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)),
  ManagedEntityHeader(
  case_role='Reference', 
  display_name='Person B', 
  entity_type='PERSON', 
  unique_id=247563788, 
  is_active='0', 
  date_created=datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 8, 21, 4, 29, 631000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))]
))]

What looks like a function within the list ends up being a class from the API that generates the actual data. With the modified string representation of the list and the classes imported, a successful solution is the following:
import os

from internal_package.swag.externalservice import PaginatedManagedEntityHeaders

from internal_package.swag.externalservice import ManagedEntityHeaders

import datetime

the_file = os.path.join(r"test_fixture.json")

file_str = open(the_file).read()

meth_that_worked = eval(file_str)


it's important to understand, this was never guaranteed to work.

@juanpa.arrivillaga It could be helpful if you elaborate here.

There is no guarantee that the string here represents valid python code, and that that call to PaginatedManagedEntityHeader, for example, will be valid. I'll reitierate again, you shouldn't be relying on the str representation of some python object as a serialization format. That isn't what it is meant to do. You really, really shouldn't do this

I don't think I'm expecting the string to represent valid python code. Looking at the errors I encountered with TzInfo(UTC), I don't think it was valid python code. I'm just trying to mimic the data I retrieve from the API as best as I can. What would you suggest doing instead of what I did?

Let's try this another way: why did you choose to create this file this way? What do you mean "mimic the data I retreived"? You are trying to serialize some object to a file. But you are just relying on the output of str to create some text. That isn't what str is meant to do (i.e. create a serialized format that can be deserialized). There are many many ways to serialize objects in Python. Choose an existing one and use it. Don't rely on hacks

I chose to create the file this way because I retrieved a list from the API that looked just like the string representation I displayed above. By "mimic the data I retrieved", I meant that I wanted to create an object that is like the one I retrieved from the API without making a call to the API. I really don't understand what an alternative approach looks like. Maybe it could be supplied in another answer?

Here is an approach that stores the data as a pickle.
from internal_package.swag.externalservice import PaginatedManagedEntityHeaders

from internal_package.swag.externalservice import ManagedEntityHeaders

import datetime

list_string = """[(3479865,
  PaginatedManagedEntityHeaders(
  success=True, 
  count=0, 
  rows=[
  ManagedEntityHeader(
  case_role='Reference',
  display_name='Person A',
  entity_type='PERSON', 
  unique_id=247878382, 
  is_active='1', 
  date_created=datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 18, 16, 29, 6, 535000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)),
  ManagedEntityHeader(
  case_role='Reference', 
  display_name='Person B', 
  entity_type='PERSON', 
  unique_id=247563788, 
  is_active='0', 
  date_created=datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 8, 21, 4, 29, 631000, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc))]
))]"""

the_list = eval(list_string)

with open("the_list.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(the_list, f)

The stored list can then be retrieved for unit testing:
with open("the_list.pkl", "rb") as f:
    the_list = pickle.load(f)

I have to change tzinfo=TzInfo(UTC) to tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc and import the functions that get called in the list.
